# « Cool » ou « chill » (Québec) et « chill » (France) ?

Tags: sens, anglais, québec, france, emprunts

Y a-t-il une quelconque nuance de sens, de registre ou autrement, ou une différence entre des locuteurs qui justifierait davantage le choix de « [cool](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/cool) » ou de « [chill](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/chill) » au Québec dans les exemples suivants ?

> Car dans la réalité, il se trouve de plus en plus de gens qui ne veulent pas mettre le temps nécessaire à l’achat d’une police d’assurance vie sur mesure. Et pour qui jaser avec un conseiller en sécurité financière un soir de semaine, ce n’est pas très *chill*!
> — Avez-vous eu le temps de corriger les travaux?
> — Oui. Je vais vous remettre ça tantôt.
> — C'est *chill*. À tout à l'heure.
> [ Exemples tirés du Wiktionnaire à « [chill](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/chill) » ]

Quel(s) équivalent(s) pourrait-on employer dans les exemples qui précèdent ?

> Cet oiseau de proie... est reconnu pour être assez *chill*...
> ([publicité](https://twitter.com/jfrobergeQc/status/1635968367726063618), Gouvernement du Québec)

Pourquoi pense-t-on ou non qu'il s'agit-il ici du sens français de l'emprunt (*tranquille, calme*) ?

Comment: Je ne pense pas avoir jamais entendu *chill* en Français en France. En revanche, *cool* est très courant.

Comment: @jlliagre *Chill* est très courant dans le langage parlé des jeunes. Je l'entends presque tous les jours je pense.

Comment: @TeleportingGoat Ah oui, je n'avais probablement pas remarqué ce mot alors. Effectivement, le mot est bien connu des jeunes que je connais avec le sens de *chill out*, mais ils ne l'utilisent pas souvent.

Comment: En Belgique, chill est utilisé à la place de "cool" par les jeunes. C'est un effet de mode assez "récent" (moins d'une dizaine d'années dirais-je) et pas largement répandu. Je pense que c'est un peu comme un superlatif (chill est plus froid que cool pour des températures, et donc au sens figuré c'est plus cool que cool)

Comment: Ça a une propriété différente selon qu'on parle d'une personne ou selon le contexte à mon avis. Dans le premier exemple ça ne peut pas signifier la même chose que quand on qualifie une personne. Dans une réponse à ce qui va se passer comme dans le deuxième exemple, ça a une valeur plus neutre. Et quand un animal est _reconnu comme étant_, on peut se demander si on va beaucoup plus loin que l'idée générique de _cool_. Je suis surtout familier avec le syntagme _c'est chill_.

Comment: @radouxju "*chill*" et "*cool*" ont un sens différent. "*chill*" c'est vraiment "détendu, tranquille, sans pression", alors que "*cool*" a le sens de "stylé, sympa, bien", etc.

Comment: Pourquoi vouloir utiliser ces anglicismes quand on s'interroge sur leur signification. Pourquoi pas des mots français?

Comment: @MasB Je ne sais pas si tu t'adressais à moi ? Un billet intéressant là-dessus : https://oreilletendue.com/2023/03/16/hasards-linguistiques/ ; aussi ceci : https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternance_codique

Comment: @TeleportingGoat En anglais, cool veut aussi dire relax, (keep cool -> restons zen) et ses différentes significations ont été importées avec lui. Ce que je veux dire c'est que chill a été importé plus tard et se distingue en fait assez peu en terme de signification (il est plus "chill" ajourd'hui de dire chill que de dire cool). Ceci étant dit, ce n'est pas du français au départ... Cool est maintenant entré dans le dictionnaire, mais chill pas encore. https://dictionnaire.lerobert.com/definition/cool